# evento com jquery

Tags: jquery

No  Html temos:

```
<div id="t1" > </div>
<div id="t2" > </div>
<div id="t3" > </div>
```

No js temo:

```
 var aux="#t";
 var count=0;

 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#t1").click(function(){  
              count=count+1;
              aux = aux.concat(count.toString()); 

        });



       $(aux ).click(function(){  

              alert("Hello!!!"); 
        });
 });
```

No segundo click ele não funciona , como posso fazer algo do gênero?

Comment: O código que colocaste aqui funciona perfeitamente: https://jsfiddle.net/dks20s7s/ O teu problema real não está descrito aqui. Adapta por favor o jsFiddle para mostrar o teu problema.

Comment: Joy Peter podes [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor o problema?

Comment: O que você precisa é transferir o evento `click` para as `div`s subsequentes para depois realizar alguma ação em cada uma delas, certo?

Comment: sim é mesmo isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando o browser lê `$(aux).click(function() {` ele já não vai mais procurar mudanças na variável `aux`, posteriores ao momento que a página carrega. Tens de mudar a lógica.

Uma sugestão é no momento do evento ocorrer verificar qual foi o `this`, ou `e.target` e comparar o seu ID para saber o que a função deve fazer.

Algo assim:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^="t"]').click(function() {
        if (this.id == 't1') count++;
       alert('O id da div clicada é: ' + this.id + '\nE o valor de count é: ' + count);
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7b7c3e8c/

Answer (score 3):

Resposta editada depois que a pergunta mudou:

Uma forma de resolver isso é registrar eventos dinâmicos. Dentro do seu clique definido você registra o clique para o elemento com nome dinâmico. Isso pode ser suficiente ou não, depende do seu caso.

Se não for, dentro do clique você dispara um evento para aquele elemento e referencia esse evento depois. Exemplo:

```js
var elem = '#elemento',
    event1 = 'fire1',
    event2 = 'fire2',
    event3 = 'fire3',
    count = 0;

// registra o clique pro primeiro elemento
$(elem).click(function() {
  count++;
  
  // registra o clique pros outros elementos em ordem
  $('body').on('click', elem+count, function() {
    // se necessário, dispara um novo evento
    $(this).trigger('fire'+count);
  });
  console.log('trigger registrado para o elemento '+count);
});

// Usando os eventos criados 
// Só disparam depois que clicar X vezes no primeiro elemento, ativando cada um
$('body').on(event1, function(e) {
  console.log('clique dinamico no elemento 1');
});

$('body').on(event2, function(e) {
  console.log('clique dinamico no elemento 2');
});

$('body').on(event3, function(e) {
  console.log('clique dinamico no elemento 3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elemento">clique</div>
<div id="elemento1">el1</div>
<div id="elemento2">el2</div>
<div id="elemento3">el3</div>
```